# Specify construct when querying with Devart.Data.Linq.DataContext.Query<T>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, devart

I'm using Devart's Linq to sql in my project (not Entity Framework). Try to select from database with `Query<T>`, or `ExecuteQuery<T>`, but `T` deliberately don't have public parameterless constructor. Can I somehow overwrite how should a new instance of `T` created? For example giving an instance of `AutoMapper.Profile` at some point? Or giving a `Func<T>` that will create the `T` instance before it's overwritten with the value from the DB?

```
using( var DC = new SomeDevartDataContextBaseDerivative() )
{
    // exception because parameterless constructor
    var FM = DC.ExecuteQuery<SomeTypeWithoutParameterlessConstructor>( "Select 1 as Id" );
    return FM;
}
```

Comment: I know I can for example create a SomeTypeWithoutParameterlessConstructor2 type with exact same parameters, and with an parameterless constructor, than map it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass a type without public parameterless constructor.

Comment: It would be nice, if implemented.

Comment: Constructors with parameters should implement logic for checking values passed and generating errors if value is invalid. Passing null (referenced type) and 0 (structure) is not a universal solution, this will not work in most cases. That's why it is not implemented.

Comment: I mean we can implement the construction logic. Like AutoMapper does with `ConstructServicesUsing` here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dependency-injection. Or MVC 5 does with `DependencyResolver.SetResolver`. So passing null will never happen. Checking values passed will be the same as before. User must take care of it.